# How do I have 2 gated builds, both stop checkin if either of them fail

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

We have a scenario in which we have 2 builds  running one after other following [this implementation](http://blog.stangroome.com/2011/09/06/queue-another-team-build-when-one-team-build-succeeds/).

but the problem is say Build1 passes, since it is a gated builds, it checks in the change set irrespective of outcome of Build2.

Can I some how have 2 builds running in series and letting changeset in only when both pass.

Comment: @Jason Stangroome your opinion is solicited ....

Answer (score 1):

No this is not possible.

Recommendation is that you only have one gated build for a branch.

Comment: True, not possible, but based on what we did at my last job it's an interesting use case. We had builds that consisted or 1 - 2 dozen builds where some ran in a certain order and some ran in parallel.  After 12 - 24 hours of building you'd finally have a complete product.   What he's hinting at is that if some checkin causes a base build that he also wants to execute other builds that have a dependency on the base build and if they fail  reject the whole thing.  Makes sense based on my experience but it's also a huge ask and goes against the notion that a CT build should be fast.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but a few years ago, I worked in a project which had such a structure, they had to edit the default template but it was 2 builds in succession that decided whether to check in or not, I some how cant get my head around working with build template..